# Why in custom class of tailwindcss I can not define 2 hover:?

Tags: tailwind-css

In Laravel 8 app with tailwindcss 2   I want to set 2 conditions on hover in custom classes :

```
.btn_action_item {
    @apply py-1 px-3 block hover:bg-green-500 hover:font-bold text-gray-100;
}
```

But I got error :

```
The `hover:font-bold` class does not exist. If you're sure that `hover:font-bold` exists, make sure that any `@import` statements are being properly processed before Tailwind CSS sees your CSS, as `@apply` can only be used for classes in the same CSS tree.
```

If I leave only 1 hover: - it is compiled ok.
Looks like that is valid syntax, but which valid ?

**MODIFIED :**
As that is laravel 8 project in the project I found only
1 file /vendor/laravel-frontend-presets/tailwindcss/src/tailwindcss-stubs/tailwind.config.js
with content :

```
module.exports = {
  purge: [
    './resources/views/**/*.blade.php',
    './resources/css/**/*.css',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
        fontFamily: { sans: ['Inter var'] },
    }
  },
  variants: {},
  plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/ui'),
  ]
}
```

as this file is under /vendor/ directory I think I have no to edit it.

also I have file webpack.mix.js with content:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        require("tailwindcss"),
    ]);
```

Not sure which file have I to edit with line :

```
fontWeight: ['hover'],
```

?

**MODIFIED 2:**

I added tailwind.config.js file in my project by editing webpack.mix.js :

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');


const tailwindcss = require('tailwindcss');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    // .sass('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css')
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        require("tailwindcss"),
    ])
    .options({
        processCssUrls: false,
        postCss: [tailwindcss('./tailwind.config.js')],
    });
```

and in tailwind.config.jsI added variants:

```
module.exports = {
    theme: {
        extend: {
            backgroundImage: theme => ({
                'test-device-sm': "url('/img/test-device/sm.png')",
                'test-device-md': "url('/img/test-device/md.png')",
                'test-device-lg': "url('/img/test-device/lg.png')",
                'test-device-xl': "url('/img/test-device/exlg.png')",
            })
        },

        variants: {
            extend: {
                fontWeight: ['hover'],
            }
        },


    }
}
```

bu Anyway adding 2 hover in resources/css/app.css :

```
.btn_action_item {
    @apply py-1 px-3 block hover:bg-green-500 hover:font-bold text-gray-100;
}
```

I got SyntaxError :

```
(234:51) /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/tAdsBack/resources/css/app.css The `hover:font-bold` class does not exist. If you're sure that `hover:font-bold` exists, make sure that any `@import` statements are being properly processed before Tailwind CSS sees your CSS, as `@apply` can only be used for classes in the same CSS tree.

  232 |     .btn_action_item {
> 233 |         @apply py-1 px-3 block hover:bg-green-500 hover:font-bold text-gray-100;
      |                                                   ^
```

I see @import in error description is mentioned. Looks like I missed it. How have I to use it ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `font-bold` class sets the font-weight CSS property. By default `hover` variant is not enabled for font-weight utility classes. You can enable it by editing your tailwind config file (`/vendor/laravel-frontend-presets/tailwindcss/src/tailwindcss-stubs/tailwind.config.js`) like so:

```js
module.exports = {
  purge: [
    './resources/views/**/*.blade.php',
    './resources/css/**/*.css',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
        fontFamily: { sans: ['Inter var'] },
    }
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {
     fontWeight: ['hover'],
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/ui'),
  ]
}
```

Refer: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/font-weight#variants

**Alternatively** you can use `:hover` pseudo-class to achieve the same effect like so:

```css
.btn_action_item {
    @apply py-1 px-3 block text-gray-100;
}
.btn_action_item:hover {
    @apply bg-green-500 font-bold;
}
```

Comment: Pls look at MODIFIED

Comment: Can you tell me which version of tailwindcss your project uses?

Comment: In package.json I found "tailwindcss": "^2.0.3"

Comment: Alright, then you need to add the above in /vendor/laravel-frontend-presets/tailwindcss/src/tailwindcss-stubs/tailwind.config.js

Comment: Editing manually files inside of /vendor is a very poor style, as its content is regenerated at composer update command...

Comment: Pls look at MODIFIED 2 with tailwind.config.js defined

Comment: @mstdmstd the alternative approach will probably work for you

Answer (score -2):

Doesn't make sense to use 2 hover for the same object. You can put all together in one hover.
Because only a hover can exist.

Comment: How  can I put all together in one hover? Which syntax is valid ?